# Groovy packaged into a Jar not working using maven. Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, maven, groovy, jar

So I have a groovy collection of packages and I have successfully packaged them into a jar file using mvn package.

I successfully added this jar file to another project which compiles just fine, but when trying to actually use the jar I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: pefservices.restapi.Request.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.restapi.Request.ViewPoint(Request.groovy:185)
at pefservices.restapi.Request.ViewPoint(Request.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.restapi.Client.profile(Client.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.restapi.Client.getName(Client.groovy:20)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.viewpoint.Client.<init>(Client.groovy:30)
at pefservices.viewpoint.Client.<init>(Client.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.viewpoint.User.<init>(User.groovy:35)
at pefservices.viewpoint.User.<init>(User.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.setup.Session.enableFramework(Session.groovy:188)
at pefservices.setup.Session.enableFramework(Session.groovy)
at pefservices.setup.Session$enableFramework.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
at main.App.main(App.groovy:15)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
pefservices.restapi.Request.getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:190)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:313)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:307)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
at pefservices.restapi.Request$_ViewPoint_closure1.doCall(Request.groovy:182)
at pefservices.restapi.Request$_ViewPoint_closure1.doCall(Request.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:122)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.get(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is the class in which it fails, it seems to happen whenever it tries to access a class property (I have tried removing those lines from this specific class and it worked just fine but then failed on another class where its getting another property)

```
import java.nio.CharBuffer
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request as Req
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder as ClientBuilder
import okhttp3.Request.Builder
import okio.Buffer
import pefservices.restapi.User as UserAPI
import pefservices.setup.*

public class Request {

Map <String, String> cache = new HashMap <String, String>()
Map <String, CompletableFuture <?>> inProcess = new HashMap <String, CompletableFuture <?>>()

//includes Authorization

public def ViewPoint(String url, String RequestMethod, def requestBody='', Map headers=[:], boolean asAdmin=true, def asUser=null) {

    if(!url.startsWith("http://"))
    {

        url='http://'+url
    }
    String toBeCached = url+RequestMethod+requestBody+headers+Values+asAdmin+asUser


    waitForRequestifExists(toBeCached)

    if(!cache.containsKey(toBeCached))
    {
        def inputLine
        inProcess.put(toBeCached, new CompletableFuture().supplyAsync(
                {
                    OkHttpClient client = new ClientBuilder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();



                    println "restAPI [$RequestMethod] URL: "+url

                    Builder builder =new Builder().url(url)

//                  headers+=["Accept-Encoding" :"gzip, deflate"]
                    headers+=["Accept"          :"application/json, text/plain, */*"]
                    headers+=["Accept-Language" :"en-US,en;q=0.5"]
                    headers+=["Expires"         :"-1"]
                    headers+=["Connection"      :"keep-alive"]

                    if(requestBody instanceof File)
                    {
                        String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();
                        headers+=['Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary]



                    }

                    if(!headers.containsKey("Content-Type"))
                    {
                        headers+=["Content-Type"    :"application/json; charset=UTF-8; odata.metadata=minimal"]
                    }

                    if (!url.contains("api/open") && url.contains(Session.url))
                    {
                        if (asAdmin==true)
                        {
                            headers+=["Authorization"   :Session.tokens['adminToken']];
                        }
                        else if(asUser!=null)
                        {
                            UserAPI userAPI = new UserAPI();
                            headers+=["Authorization"   :userAPI.loginPost(asUser).Token]
                        }
                        else{
                            headers+=["Authorization"   :Session.tokens['userToken']];
                        }
                    }

                    for(entry in headers) {
                        builder.addHeader(entry.key, entry.value)

                    }



                    if (!(requestBody instanceof String) && headers['Content-Type'].toString().contains("json"))
                    {

                        requestBody = JsonOutput.toJson(requestBody)

                    }


                    if (RequestMethod != 'GET')
                    {

                        try{
                            println "Json body:->"+ JsonOutput.prettyPrint(requestBody)
                        }
                        catch (Throwable ex)
                        {
                            println "body:"+ requestBody
                        }
                        if(requestBody instanceof File)
                        {
                            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(headers['Content-Type']), requestBody)
                            RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                    .addFormDataPart("file", requestBody.getName(), body)
                                    .build()

                            builder.method(RequestMethod, formBody)

                        }
                        else{

                            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(headers['Content-Type']), requestBody)
                            builder.method(RequestMethod, body)
                        }
                    }
                    Req request = builder.build()

                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                    int responseCode = response.code()
                    String responseTitle = response.message()

                    if(response.header("Content-Disposition")?.contains('attachment'))
                    {
                        String header =response.header("Content-Disposition")
                        String fileExtension = header.substring(header.lastIndexOf('.'))
                        println "Content-Disposition: attachment  - File Extension ->$fileExtension"

                        File file = new File(".\\TestFiles\\temp$fileExtension")
                        InputStream IS= response.body().byteStream()

                        BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(IS);
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0

                        int count
                        while ((count =input.read(data)) != -1) {

                            total += count;
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        inputLine = file
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        inputLine = response.body().string()
                    }

                    println "RESTAPI Response Code: -> "+ responseCode 
                    if (responseCode >= 400)
                    {
                        println "Message: -> " + responseTitle
                        println "Error Resposne body:  -> "+inputLine
                        throw new Exception("Error Code =$responseCode   URL:  $url")
                    }
```

Fails specifically in the below line

```
                    cache[toBeCached] = inputLine
                }, new Executors().newSingleThreadExecutor()))

        inProcess[toBeCached].get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        inProcess.remove(toBeCached)

        if(RequestMethod == "POST")
            {println "restapi.Request() ->"+inputLine

            }
        return inputLine
    }
    else
    {
        return cache.get(toBeCached)
    }


}
public void waitForRequestifExists(String key)
{
    if(inProcess.containsKey(key))
    {
        this.inProcess[key].get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}
public void clearCache()
{
    this.cache = new HashMap <String, String>()
    this.inProcess = new HashMap <String, CompletableFuture <?>>()
}
}
```

Comment: Which maven plugin do you use to compile groovy files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was seeing AbstractMethodError in our maven project. Seems the problem was that the version of groovy-all and and groovy-eclipse-batch should match. Comment from eric-milles in this [groovy-eclipse issue](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1078) was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, it turned out that maven plugins used to compile groovy code had some issues. I solved it by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681180/2400849).

Basically you need to explicitly specify versions of `groovy-eclipse-compiler` and `groovy-eclipse-batch`. In my POM I had *metaversion* value set to `LATEST`. Instead, try using concrete values like `<version>3.6.0-03</version>`. (Try clearing your .m2 repository cache after that.)

This is applicable if you use these plugins in your build process.